# Проблема отображения своих шрифтов в Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, шрифты

Есть страница **www/index.html** с меню, где используются "свои" шрифты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю копию файла в папку **www/folder/index.html**, меняю пути к файлам стилей и где подключаются шрифты и все работает как надо, за исключением браузера **Firefox v41.0**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в "Скомпилированном стиле" пишет что он подключен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шрифты подлючаю так:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "GothamProBold";
    src: url("../fonts/GothamProBold.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/GothamProBold.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/GothamProBold.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/GothamProBold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

В других браузерах все отображается нормально.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как ее забороть?

Comment: Firefox всегда выделялся, а шрифты сами конвертировали, и где скачивали?

Comment: @emtecif, .ttf от дизайнера, а конвертирую на https://www.web-font-generator.com/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте прогнать здесь http://www.font2web.com/ Единственный конвертер, который нормально работает, во всяком случае у меня.

Answer (score 0):

Были такие же проблемы.  Вообще шрифты лучше не конвертировать, а искать уже готовые для веба. Скачайте и используйте [эти](http://fonts4web.ru/gothampro.html) шрифты.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "GothamProBlack";
    src: url("../fonts/GothamProBlack/GothamProBlack.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/GothamProBlack/GothamProBlack.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/GothamProBlack/GothamProBlack.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/GothamProBlack/GothamProBlack.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Попробовал у себя, версия 41.0.1, шрифты отображаются корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: ниче не понял..

Comment: @emtecif это стандартный комментарий, который добавляется при просмотре сообщения из очереди "низкокачественных" - у вас сообщение слишком короткое, и система закинула его на проверку. Просто распишите, почему именно эти шрифты, и чем они помогут в конкретной ситуации. Ответы со ссылкой без пояснений - зло. Ссылки умирают со временем.

Comment: Файлы по ссылке, байт в байт как мои и стиль тоже(

Comment: всё работает нормально, обновил ответ